# Weird tesselation in multires bake

Tags: texture-baking, baking, sculpt, multiresolution

I'm experiencing weird baking tessellation when using multires. I've sculpted details on some low poly legs I've done. Nothing too complex.. Has anyone gotten an idea of how come this occurs? I would say I've tried most things, like checking normals, applying transformations etc.
I'm using a 1080TI graphics card, if this could have anything to do with the issue.
Blender version 3.5.1.

[image: Example screenshot]

[image: Example of low poly + sculpted version of mesh.]